# Vue CLI - no .env file found in Vue.js project root

Tags: vue.js, environment-variables, development-environment, production-environment, vue-cli-4

I created a project with Vue CLI 4.1.2, and inside `router/index.js`, I found:

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})
```

There is no `.env` file in the project root. So what does `process.env.BASE_URL` mean? Where is the `BASE_URL` value set?

Answer (score 0):

[`process.env`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env) is a property that contains the user's environment variables in Node. The [`.env`](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables) is an **optional** file that could be used in Vue CLI projects to create additional environment variables. Note that you could also create `.env.production` and `.env.development` files to set variables specific to the current build mode.

`BASE_URL` is an environment variable automatically set by Vue CLI when running `serve` or `build` NPM scripts. Its default value is `/`, but it can be configured in `<projectRoot>/vue.config.js` with the [`baseUrl`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#baseurl) (deprecated) or [`publicPath`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath) setting:

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  publicPath: '/my-app/'
}
```

Comment: Where in the Vue Cli project is the property `process.env` set ?

Comment: The Node runtime sets that property. It's a feature of Node, not Vue CLI.